# Como usar model-viewer no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Boa tarde.

Não estou conseguindo usar a tag  no React. Alguém sabe qual é o problema? Eu tinha seguido esse [tutorial](https://dev.to/theranbrig/add-ar-and-3d-models-to-any-site-in-minutes-3co6)

Usando apenas HTML funciona normal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbTtU.png 
No entanto, quando tento utilizar no React o resultado é esse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV9HS.png

Esse é o site da documentação do modelviewer: https://modelviewer.dev/

Trecho do código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Coloquei uma print porque quando tava tentando usar o code ou pre ficava faltando uma parte do código

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu tbm estava com esse mesmo problema!

Eu segui esse tutorial utilizando a lib [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

Primeiro de tudo, vc instala a lib via npm com o comando:

```
npm install --save react-helmet
```

Depois disso, vai na página no qual você quer aplicar o model-viewer e importa a lib:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
```

Feito isso, tudo o que precisamos fazer é colocar esse cara dentro do return do método render no meio do nosso componente, passando um atributo para aplicar. No nosso caso, é o script do model viewer:

```
<Helmet>
   <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
</Helmet>
```

Espero que o post te ajude em seus projetos de alguma forma e qualquer dúvida que tiver só entrar em contato comigo.

Instagram: @joaomiiiguel